# SUMPRODUCT ( 1/COUNTIF( range, criteria)). WHY DOES THIS WORK

Tags: excel, distinct, countif, sumproduct

I need to count how many different values are in a range. I got the answer by using `SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A37,A2:37))`, however, I don't understand the formula, can someone please help me explain?

If I do the `COUNTIF` separately, the result is `0`? How does `SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF)` help? Also, inside the `COUNTIF`, the `range` and `criteria` are the same, what does this mean? I understand that the `range` is where we look for, and the `criteria` is for what criteria, but if the `criteria` is the entire `range`, how are we specifying what we're looking for here? How does this translate/work?

Here my sample input:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29v7V.png)

Comment: `COUNTIF(A2:A37,A2:37)` will count each item how many times appear in list. Then `1/COUNTIF(A2:A37,A2:37)` will make a fraction value of of each item as per count. Then you sum that fraction values to get total, which is equivalent to distinct count. You can do it by `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(A2:A37))` in ***Microsoft-365***.

Comment: It also has to do with implicit intersection vs dynamic arrays. In older versions of Excel SUMPRODUCT() is one of the few functions that can overcome implicit intersection. With ms365 you can change this to SUM() to see how dynamic arrays would work and calculate.

Comment: So, how did you work out that solution, if you don't know how it works??

Comment: Thank you @Harun24hr, I'll also try out that formula!

Comment: Thank you @JvdV for the information, I'll research more on that!

Comment: Hi @SolarMike, thanks for the question, I luckily got to that formula by playing around with the formulas but were not able to understand them, it was just by luck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extend some of the comments provided in your question for a better understanding. Here: [Excel dynamic arrays, functions and formulas](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-dynamic-arrays-functions-formulas/#:%7E:text=Dynamic%20Arrays%20are%20resizable%20arrays,%2D%20one%20formula%2C%20one%20cell.) you can find a detail explanation about *dynamic arrays* and *implicit interception* and how it has changed through Excel evolution.

`SUMPRODUCT (array1, [array2], ...)` can be used with a single argument, in such case it sums all elements in `array1`, i.e. similar to `SUM` function ([Excel SUMPRODUCT Function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function)). For example: `SUMPRODUCT({1;2;3}) = 6`.

**Note**: Multiplication is the default operation of `SUMPRODUCT`, but you can use others (check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)) replacing the `,` with the corresponding operation. For example: `SUMPRODUCT({1;2;3}/({1;2;3}))=3` (acts as `COUNT`), i.e. `1/1+2/2+3/3` but `SUMPRODUCT({1;2;3},{1;2;3})=14`, i.e. `1*1+2*2+3*3`.

`COUNTIF(range, criteria)` the first argument *has* to be a range, but the second argument can be a number, expression, cell reference, or text string that determines which cells will be counted, *but* it also can be a range or an array ([Excel COUNTIF function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countif-function)). If that is the case, `COUNTIF` is invoked for each element of `criteria` and returns an array of the *same size and shape* as `criteria`. For example if the following range `A1:A4` has the following values:

```
|1|
|2|
|1|
|1|
```

the following expressions will return:

```
COUNTIF(A1:A4, 1) = 3
COUNTIF(A1:A4, A1:A2) = {3;1} i.e. 2x1 array
COUNTIF(A1:A4, {1;2}) = {3;1}
COUNTIF(A1:A4, {1,2}) = {3,1} i.e. 1x2 array
```

and for a two dimensional criteria `{1,2;0,1}` a `2x2` array:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A4, {1,2;0,1}) = ={3,1;0,3} i.e. 2x2 array
```

**Note**: Remember you *can not* invoke the function with the first input argument as an array, for example: `COUNTIF({1;2;1;1}, 1)` returns an error. It *has* to be a range.

so we can count how many times each element of the first input argument is repeated like this:

```
COUNTIF(A1:A4,A1:A4) = {3;1;3;3} i.e. 4x1 array
```

Now back to `SUMPRODUCT` (remember with a single argument it is just the sum of the elements):

```
SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A4,A1:A4)) 
 = SUMPRODUCT({3;1;3;3})
 = 10
```

i.e. sum of occurrences of each element of `A1:A4`

and finally:

```
SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A1:A4,A1:A4)) 
 = SUMPRODUCT({1/3;1/1;1/3;1/3})
 = 3*(1/3) + 1 
 = 2
```

which results in total total number of unique elements in `A1:A4`. As @Harun24hr pointed out, it can be achieved in **Microsoft 365** with: `COUNTA(UNIQUE(A1:A4)` or also `COUNT(UNIQUE(A1:A4)` since in the example of this answer `A1:A4` are numbers, but in the sample of your question (letters) you *have* to use: `COUNTA`.

Comment: Thank you so much David, this totally makes sense and helps a lot :) Appreciate your time!